# Find SUM of ALL items within a Order mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I have two tables

**Orders**
- ID
- Date
- Vendor

**Items**
- ID
- OrderID
- Price
- Qty

I'm trying to display the total of all items within the order. Something like this..

- 101 - 12/02/2017 - Sams - $327
- 105 - 12/05/2017 - Sams - $544

Instead my results are showing like this..

- 101 - 12/02/2017 - Sams - $300
- 101 - 12/02/2017 - Sams - $27
- 105 - 12/05/2017 - Sams - $200
- 105 - 12/05/2017 - Sams - $344

So it is giving me the total for each item in the order, but not the total for ALL items in the order which is what I'm after.  Here is my current query.

```
SELECT o.id AS oid, o.date AS date, (i.price*i.qty) AS subtotal FROM orders o, items i WHERE o.cosid=? AND o.id=i.OrderID GROUP BY o.id ORDER BY o.id DESC LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: Add `o.date` to the `Group By` clause.

Comment: We don't need the PHP, old style joins need to die already, don't include a field in the select unless you plan to aggregate it or group by that field

Comment: If it were me, I'd use application code, not sql, to get the overall sum.

Comment: they can have multiple orders on the smae date from the same company so i'm not sure adding o.date to group by is correct?

Comment: You're aggregating on the date, so you'll need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT o.id AS oid, o.date AS date, SUM(i.price*i.qty) AS total_per_order_date 
  FROM orders o 
INNER JOIN items i 
    ON o.id = i.orderid 
 GROUP BY o.id,o.date 
ORDER BY o.id,o.date ;
```

Comment: You fixed the join too, so I think this one is best.

Comment: Think i explained wrong, as I do not need the date in the group by just the OrderID. This way it totals all line items for that orderID, but not all items on that date.. Everything else works great!! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the date to your `GROUP BY` clause and apply the `SUM()` function to sum the prices:

```
SELECT o.id AS oid, 
  o.date AS date, 
  SUM(i.price*i.qty) AS subtotal 
FROM orders o, items i 
WHERE o.cosid=? 
  AND o.id=i.OrderID 
GROUP BY o.id,o.date
ORDER BY o.id 
DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: This worked as well. thank you for the advice and help!

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
sum(i.price*i.qty) as subtotal
```

otherwise you are just calculating a result for each item.

Comment: This worked as well. thank you for the advice and help!